# Pagination Not Working When Modifying Loop Based on Post Category

Tags: pagination, loop

I have added query_posts() to my index.php file to modify the loop on the posts page:

```
query_posts( 'cat=-4,-7' );
get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
```

This works correctly, but when I click on "Older Posts" (link to /page/2), the latest posts show up instead of the previous ones. How can I get my pagination to show the correct posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

different approach:

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'category__not_in' => array(4,7) ) );
query_posts( $args );
get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
```

if this approach should not work, please check if one or more of the plugins is interfering - deactivate all plugins; if the exclusion of categories works then, re-activate one plugin at a time to find the interfering plugin.

Comment: That does not actually work. The posts with category 4 or 7 are still showing up.

Comment: answer edited; rewritten with different query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string.'&cat=-4,-7' );
```